# handle jQuery hover behavior

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I've made a simple example with my problem so I guess it's easier for you to understand.
I have a few `div`s which all have a grey color, but when you hover over one of them, you see they get their true color.
If I click one of them (and it alerts clicked) it should change the color and the `.hover()` shouldn't work anymore on this element, until another one is clicked.
I'm sitting here one hour and don't get it to work:

```
.test { background-color: #ccc;}
<div class="test" id="d1"></div>
<div class="test" id="d2"></div>
<div class="test" id="d3"></div>
```

and the script:

```
$(function() {
$('#d1').hover(function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#F00'); }, function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC'); });
$('#d2').hover(function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#F0F'); }, function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC'); });
$('#d3').hover(function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#00F'); }, function() { $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC'); });

$('#d1').click(function() { $(this).css('background-color','#F00'); alert("clicked")});
$('#d2').click(function() { $(this).css('background-color','#F0F'); alert("clicked")});
$('#d3').click(function() { $(this).css('background-color','#00F'); alert("clicked")});
```

})

for the link click [here](http://super-sized.de/test.html)

It seems that the hover still works and it removes the background color immediately.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So when a div is clicked, the color should remain, even if another element is hovered over, until another element is clicked?

Comment: the element which is last clicked remains in its color. all other divs acting like always.

Comment: Well, a step in the right direction, use the `.mouseover()` event, since it will keep the css fired. When you hover, it includes both the mouseover and mouseoff event.

Comment: @supersize You need a way to decide if the element has already been clicked, and remember that setting so the color can 'stick'. You can use classes for that. If the element has the class 'stick', then don't change the color on hover.  See my example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [without *too many* changes to your code](http://jsfiddle.net/MgTr4/) [refactoring]:

```
$(function() {
    var clickedId = '';

    $('#d1').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#F00'); 
    }, function() { 
        if (this.id != clickedId) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC');
        }
    });
    $('#d2').hover(function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color', '#F0F'); 
    }, function() { 
        if (this.id != clickedId) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC');
        }     
    });
    $('#d3').hover(function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color', '#00F');
    }, function() {
        if (this.id != clickedId) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC');
        }
    });

    $('#d1').click(function() {
        clickedId = this.id;
        $('.test').not(this).css('background-color','#CCC');
        alert("clicked");
    });
    $('#d2').click(function() {
        clickedId = this.id;
        $('.test').not(this).css('background-color','#CCC');
        alert("clicked");
    });
    $('#d3').click(function() {
        clickedId = this.id;
        $('.test').not(this).css('background-color','#CCC');
        alert("clicked");
    });

 })
```

Changes:

- Use a variable to hold the ID of the last clicked element
- When you click an element, store the id of that clicked element. Also, set all elements (except the one you clicked) back to the original background color.
- On hover out, check if the element losing hover is the id of the last clicked element (if it is, don't change its background back).

As an aside, I would probably use CSS classes and set `.active` to the clicked elements, and use `.test:hover`. But I assume this was a rudimentary JavaScript example for learning purposes.

And if you wanted to see the one with CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/MgTr4/1/

Comment: thanks for your effort. This is indeed exactly what I was looking for. I know all the css possibilities, but it isn't as simple as in my example. If I had linked my original code, no one would understand what I meant. Anyways, thanks for that snippet above, solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="test" data-selected-item="d1" id="d1"></div>
<div class="test" data-selected-item="d2" id="d2"></div>
<div class="test" data-selected-item="d3" id="d3"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test { margin-left: 50px; background-color:#CCC; height: 50px; width: 50px; float: left; margin-top: 50px; }
.d1 { background-color : #F00 !important;}
.d2{ background-color : #F0F !important;}
.d3 { background-color : #00F !important;}
```

**JS**

```
  $(function() {
    $('.test').click(function() {
        $(this).hasClass($(this).data('selected-item')) ? $(this).removeClass($(this).data('selected-item')) : $(this).addClass($(this).data('selected-item'));
    });
});
```

Sample
http://jsfiddle.net/sheeban/gEftm/3/

Comment: this is  sample snippet it will maintain the state of the color.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code greatly by using classes, and the jQuery methods `.addClass` and `.removeClass`

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XD4zu/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test" id="d1" mycolor='#F00'></div>
<div class="test" id="d2" mycolor='#F0F'></div>
<div class="test" id="d3" mycolor='#00F'></div>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
$('.test').hover(
    function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('stick') == false) {
            $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('mycolor') );
        }
    },function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('stick') == false) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#CCC');
        }
});
$('div').click(function() {
    $('div').removeClass('stick');
    $(this).addClass('stick');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.test { background-color: #ccc;}
div{width:150px;height:80px;margin:5px;}
```

---

To simplify it even more, you can remove the `class="test"` from all DIVs, and change the hover selector to:

```
$('div').hover( etc etc
```

This will not interfere with detecting the `click` event on the same collection of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a really simple solution:

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/uPucInO/1/edit)

```
  $('.test').hover(function( e ){
    var hc = $(this).hasClass('test');
    $(this).css({ backgroundColor : (e.type=="mouseleave" && hc) ? '#ccc' :  $(this).data('c') });
  }).click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('test test2 ');
  });
```

having this HTML:

```
<div class="test" id="d1" data-c="#f00"></div>
<div class="test" id="d2" data-c="#f0f"></div>
<div class="test" id="d3" data-c="#00f"></div>
```

and both classes in CSS:

```
.test, .test2{
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use css in this situation. JavaScript solution is more complicated. In your case you can change your "hover" block of code and change it to css rules:

```
#d1:hover { background-color: #F00; }
#d2:hover { background-color: #F0F; }
#d3:hover { background-color: #00F; }
```

Here is an example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y68QK/), after edit: [jsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Y68QK/1/)

Comment: Except clicking (with css) wouldn't hold the color until the next click.

Comment: @BradChristie I haven't noticed it required, I have edit my answer.